# Simplification of Taylor Series of ln(x) about 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

While calculating the Taylor series of $ln(x)$ about the point $x_0=1$ I found the following:

$f(x) = \frac{1}{1!}(x-1)^1-\frac{1}{2!}(x-1)^2+\frac{2}{3!}(x-1)^3+…$

From this, I generalized the summation as $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}  (-1)^{n+1}\frac{(x-1)^n}{n!}(x-1)^n$

However, when I tried to verify my calculation on [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=f9476968629e1163bd4a3ba839d60925&title=Taylor%20Series&theme=blue&i0=ln(x)&i1=x&i2=1&i3=10&podSelect=&showAssumptions=1&showWarnings=1) this sum was written without the factorial in the denominator. Where exactly does the factorial go to, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numerators are actually $(n-1)!$, so $(n-1)!/n!=1/n$.